# Password isn't getting hashed by brcypt module

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am hashing password using nodejs "bcrypt" module. this is my hashing function...

[image]
 and here i am calling my function 
[image]

But in databases password is not saving. In databases field is empty every time when i register. How can i fix it?

Here is database entry record
[image]

Comment: what do you get if you log the result of `hash` inside your helper function ?

Comment: please see updated post

Comment: Instead of screenshotting your code you should put your code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing saved inside your database because you choose to use the asynchronous bcrypt hash function.

It should work if you use the synchronous one. ( replace your bcrypt hash by this one)

```
let hash = bcrypt.hashSync('password', 10);
return hash;
```

Comment: I have tried with hashSync too but still password isn't saving in db

Comment: so can you tell me what is the output of `password` and `hash` inside your hashPassword function ?

Comment: i won't rebuild your full project with one page. I just need you to test and tell me what's the output of the two variables. because you can just have an error sending your password.

Comment: the output of "password" argument inside my helper function is that i am passing from postman which is "123456" and i place console.log for "hash" variable also but it is not logging on console

Comment: i was not saving password in hash variable in a way u mentioned like this
let hash = .....  that's why password is not saving